# Wordpress Theme Customization - Changing "log in" button to "myTransplantoux" after login

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, themes, customization

I'm wondering if there is a way to change an element of my theme as soon a user succesfully logged in.

The 'log-in' button at the top right of the primary menu should be replaced by another button 'myTransplantoux' which is linked to the my-account pages of WooCommerce.

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Please add the relevant code for how you have added the button in the first place.

Comment: Hi, I'm using a child theme of OnePress. As part of the primary menu, i have a navigation to a page called 'aanmelden' (which is dutch for 'log in'). After a succesfull login i want to change this navigation label 'aanmelden' to 'myTransplantoux'.

Comment: You can add the link via code, see [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/156261/6477). Or you could add a second menu item for the "My Account" and then use my plugin [Nav Menu Roles](https://wordpress.org/plugins/nav-menu-roles/) to control when each is displayed.